# String-match: symbols variable void

Tags: regular-expressions, quote

I am trying to write a small function where I extract two sub-strings from a cite-key, e.g. `cite:rammstein2017paris`.

```
(defun citekey-get-author-and-year ()
          "Get the _author_ and _YEAR_ from a cite:authorYEARtitle key."
          (interactive) ; allow this to be user-callable
          (let
              ((regexp ":\(.*\)\([0-9]*\)[a-z]") ; the regex to parse
               author
               year
               (citekey (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))))
        
          (when (string-match 'regexp 'citekey)
            (setq author (match-string 1 string)
                  year (match-string 2 string)))
          )
```

The above code gives me a "Wrong type argument: stringp, regexp" error. I came up with it after reading the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Accessing-Variables.html#Accessing-Variables). If I do it without the `'regexp 'citekey` line, I get the error "Symbols value as a variable is void: regexp".

Based on the error description, the function doesn't know what regexp and citekey are, but why?

---

I tried debugging it with `debug-on-entry`, as described [here](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/emacs-lisp-intro_18.html). Unfortunately I did not really see or understand where the error is.

My code is inspired by the `string-match` documentation, and it confuses me very much that it doesn't work.

```
Demos
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
(let ((string "Today is <2018-11-07>."))
  (when (string-match "<\\([-0-9]+\\)>" string)
    (match-string 1 string)))
#+END_SRC
```

When searching online for the error code, there are a bunch of results, but as the error seems very generic I didn't find anything that solved my problem.

---

I believe that the mistake is really basic and obvious, it is just that my understanding of elisp is lacking, as this is the first function I write.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: To many questions - this essentially amounts to Please fix my code. There's the quote of `regexp` (which you removed in your own answer), and the wrong regexp, and... Please submit only one, specific question per question. Thx.

Comment: Interesting, so it is true what they say about stackoverflow and stackexchange.

I am a new user, I read the on-boarding, I tag my question, I get a badge, and the first thing I get as feedback is that everything I did was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the corrected incantation:

```el
(defun my-citekey-get-author-and-year ()
  "Get the AUTHOR and YEAR from a cite:AUTHORYEARtitle key."
  (interactive) ; allow this to be user-callable
  (let ((regexp ":\\(.*\\)\\([0-9]*\\)[a-z]") ; the regex to parse
        (citekey (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position)
                                   (line-end-position)))
        author year)
    (when (string-match regexp citekey)
      (setq author (match-string 1 citekey)
            year (match-string 2 citekey)))))
```

Note the fixed parentheses around `let`'s bindings, regexp backslash syntax, variable referencing, and second argument to `match-string`, which needs to be the same string passed to `string-match`.

In brief, the value of `'foo` is the canonical symbol with the name `foo`, whereas the value of `foo` is the value stored in the variable whose name is the symbol `foo`.

For example, `(setq foo 1)` is actually shorthand for `(set 'foo 1)`.

Comment: How do I have to understand the "canonical symbol"? I never head that term. Can I say that  "$" is the canonical symbol for dollar?

Comment: @jsteinbach What I meant by "canonical" is "unique interned", i.e. writing `'foo` creates a single unique symbol in the global obarray called `foo`. Similarly for the dollar symbol: `(eq (intern "$") '$)`

Comment: For more on symbols, see [`(info "(elisp) Symbol Type")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Type.html) and [`(info "(elisp) Symbols")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbols.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it myself. Apparently I have to run my code *inside* the let(), not *outside*.

The following works (= does not throw an error). Note the brackets.

```
(defun citekey-get-author-and-year ()
  "Get the _author_ and _YEAR_ from a cite:authorYEARtitle key."
  (interactive) ; allow this to be user-callable
  (let
      ((regexp ":\(.*\)\([0-9]*\)[a-z]") ; the regex to parse
       author
       year
       (citekey (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))))
    ; body
    (message regexp)
    (message citekey)
    (when (string-match ":\(.*\)\([0-9]*\)[a-z]" citekey)
      (when (string-match regexp 'citekey)
        (setq author (match-string 1 string)
              year (match-string 2 string))))
    (message "---")
    (message author)
    (message year)
    ))
```

---

Now I only got to fix the regexp! :)

---

E2: This is what I came up with myself.

```
(defun citekey-get-author-and-year ()
  "Get the _author_ and _YEAR_ from a cite:authorYEARtitle key."
  (interactive) ; allow this to be user-callable
  (let
      (
       ;; (regexp ":\(.*\)\([0-9]*\)[a-z]") ; the regex to parse
       (regexp (rx ":"
                   (group (zero-or-more letter))
                   (group (one-or-more digit))
                   (one-or-more letter)
                   ))
       author
       year
       (citekey (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))))
                                        ; body
    (message regexp)
    (message citekey)
    (when (string-match regexp citekey)
      (setq author (match-string 1 citekey)
            year (match-string 2 citekey)))
    (message "---")
    (message (concat author " + " year))
    ))
```